# eigenfunction of Schrodinger equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I am trying to derive the eigenfunctions from $$-\frac{1}{2}\partial_x^2\phi_k(x)+\frac{1}{2}x^2\phi_k(x)=\lambda_k\phi_k(x).$$

I got stuck here. I don't know which method I need to use.

Actually, I have $$\partial_x^2\phi_k(x)=(x^2-2\lambda_k)\phi_k(x).$$
Any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the quantum harmonic oscillator equation.  If you start with the anzatz that $$
\phi_k(x) = H_k(x) e^{-ax^2}
$$ where $H_k$(x) is required to be a polynomial, you will find that $\{\lambda_m\}$ are all in a linear progression, and the 
$H_k$ are the Hermite polynomials.

Comment: thank you! I will try now.

Comment: are there any conditions for $a$?

Comment: can I say that $a=1/2$?

Comment: You put $a$ into your anzatz so that you can adjust its value to make the solution come out to be possible.  I quess you could have guessed that $a=\frac12$, but for those of us who are not that smart, it is better to make your ansatz farily general and adjust the parameters after working with it for a while.